# Including css files conditionally in OctoberCMS

Tags: css, octobercms

In OctoberCMS I can inject a CSS file into my page using:

```
public function onRun()
{
    $this->addCss('http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/grids-responsive-min.css');
}
```

I don't know though, how can I check the IE version in the code above? What's the equivalent of the following CSS code in OctoberCMS?

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/grids-responsive-old-ie-min.css">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/grids-responsive-min.css">
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 3):

The conditional markup you posted as a reference is a HTML conditional markup and therefore cannot be used in the PHP method `onRun`.

However, you can use the same conditional markup in your theme layout - or in a specific page.

Let's suppose you're using the `demo` theme.

- Go to `themes/demo/layout/default.htm`
- Find the `head` section of your HTML document

Paste your code:

````
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/grids-responsive-old-ie-min.css">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/grids-responsive-min.css">
<!--<![endif]-->```
````

Remember to remove the `addCss` call from your `onRun` method to avoid adding the same stylesheet twice.